# Adding python to /usr/bin/env python variable

Tags: linux, python, environment-variables

The `#!/usr/bin/env` python hashbang isn't working on my Ubuntu install.

I tried the following:

```
root@x# python=/usr/bin/python
root@x# PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `env | grep PATH` and `env python --version` and `which python`?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what's not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash (which you probably are in a default Ubuntu install) you need to use `export` to set an environment variable on the command line.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

See @chaos's comment as well. Make sure `env` is showing your proper `$PATH`, eg:

```
bash-3.2$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```